# Hotkeys in PHPStorm don't work

Tags: release-juno, keyboard-layout, java

elementary OS 5 Juno with the 4.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu kernel is installed on my laptop. However, popular hot keys (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) do not work in PHPStorm 2019.2.1 and 2019.2.2, whereas they do work in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. [PHPStorm](https://snapcraft.io/phpstorm) is installed via Snap.

How may I resolve this?

Comment: Would you please open the Pantheon terminal and also the Code editor, and confirm Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V work in them? Once you have, please click [edit] and add the results into your question. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit]. Editing tips are at http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code